# Active Directory User Group Memberships GroupPrincipal

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to use `GroupPrincipal` (part of the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace) to populate a list of type string, so I can check to see if a user is a member of an Active Directory group. Here is the edited class that I have written so far:

```
public class ActiveDirectoryMembership
{
    private PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName);
    private List<string> GroupName {get;set;}

    public ActiveDirectoryMembership() 
    {
         //Code snipped - this part returns a list of users
         populateGroups();
    }

    private void populateGroups()
    {
        GroupPrincipal SearchGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "Group Name");
        GroupName = new List<string>();
        foreach (UserPrincipal p in GroupName.GetMembers())
        {
           GroupName.add(p.SamAccountName);
        }
    }
```

So, where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you see, what do you **expect** to see???

Comment: Matt this is not a real question, how does this code work? Which results do you get? How does it behave at debug time if you check with breakpoints? What do you want to get differently than what you are getting now?

Comment: Sorry, i am not getting a list of users; the value of GroupName is null.  I expect to see a list of users ( I know there are users who are a member of that group) - does that make sense?

Answer (score 4):

This modification of your code works (I made tests to ensure):

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;


    private static readonly string DomainName = "domaincontrollercomputer.domain.com";
    private static readonly string DomainContainer = "DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM";
    private static readonly string ADGroupName = "AD Group Name";
    private List<string> GroupName {get;set;}
      
    private void populateGroups()
    {
        using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainName, DomainContainer))
        {
            using (var grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, ADGroupName))
            {
                GroupName = new List<string>();
                foreach (var member in grp.GetMembers())
                {
                    GroupName.Add(member.SamAccountName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a simple typo in your method - you're getting the group principal into `SearchGroup` (check for **NULL**, btw!!) and then you're grabbing the members off `GroupName` ??

Try this:

```
private void populateGroups()
{
    GroupPrincipal SearchGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "Group Name");

    if(SearchGroup != null)
    {
       GroupName = new List<string>();

       // call 'GetMembers' on 'SearchGroup' here!! 
       foreach (UserPrincipal p in SearchGroup.GetMembers())  
       {
          GroupName.add(p.SamAccountName);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not getting a run-time/compile error.  Do I need to populate the value of P (effectivly giving me a list of users to loop through before running through the foreach loop?

Comment: Completely ignore me - my test was playing with my head - I did assert.isnull and not assert.isnotnull - all is ok now!