# Get all AD users from Specified Group

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to read all members of ever AD Group. I get the groups with following code

```
PrincipalContext yourOU = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "test.domain.CH", "OU=Verteiler,OU=Gruppen,OU=SGV,OU=Gruppe_04,OU=Kunden,DC=test,DC=domain,DC=CH");
GroupPrincipal findAllGroups = new GroupPrincipal(yourOU, "*");
PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(findAllGroups);
foreach (var group in ps.FindAll())
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.DisplayName);                    
}
```

Now I'm trying to show every user from every group.

[image]

How can I handle this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Active Directory User Group Memberships GroupPrincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247263/active-directory-user-group-memberships-groupprincipal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it by myself, please call the following Code in your foreach and send your Groupname with

```
 static async void populateGroups(string ADGroupName)
    {
        // set up domain context
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        // find the group in question
        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, ADGroupName);

        // if found....
        if (group != null)
        {
            // iterate over members
            foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
            {
               // Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);

                // do whatever you need to do to those members
                UserPrincipal theUser = p as UserPrincipal;



                if (theUser != null)
                {
                    if (theUser.IsAccountLockedOut())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The user: {0} is member of following Group {1}", theUser, ADGroupName);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The user: {0} is member of following Group {1}", theUser, ADGroupName);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```